# How can I do multithreading in Java faster?

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, optimization

I tried to implement multithreading in Java by using executor service approach. Here is my code:

```
public class GetResponseContentWithExecutorService {
 private static final int MYTHREADS = 30;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
     ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(MYTHREADS);
     String[] urlList ={"url1", "url2", "url3" ...};

    for (int i = 0; i < urlList.length; i++) {
    String baseUrl = "myUrl";
    Runnable worker = new MyRunnable(baseUrl, urlList[i].split("-")[0], urlList[i].split("-")[1]);
    executor.execute(worker);
   }

   executor.shutdown();

    while (!executor.isTerminated()) {

    }
    System.out.println("\nCompleted all threads");
  }
}

public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
   private final String baseUrl;
   private final String a;
   private final String b;

  MyRunnable(String baseUrl, String a, String b) {
    this.baseUrl = baseUrl;
    this.a= a;
    this.b= b;
 }

 @Override
    public void run() {
    String result = "";
    int code = 200;
    try {
        URL siteURL = new URL(baseUrl + a + b);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) siteURL.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setConnectTimeout(3000);
        connection.connect();

        code = connection.getResponseCode();
        if (code == 200) {
             result = "-> Succ<-\t" + "Code: " + code;
            } else {
                result = "-> NoSuc <-\t" + "Code: " + code;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
         result = e.getMessage();
       }
     System.out.println(code);
  }
}
```

The thing is that for about 30 urls I need to wait approx.40seconds and I would like to make it way faster. Any suggestions to what am I doing wrong here? 
Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: If you only have one core available, then `while (!executor.isTerminated()) {}` may be stealing all your CPU.  regardless, you should use `awaitTermination` instead

Comment: If that's not the problem, possible explanations include 1) you are saturating your local network, 2) you are saturating the server or 3) the server is rate limiting your requests.